# File loses Read-Only attribute when moved to a network drive

Tags: windows, permissions, network-drive

I currently have a batch script creating a backup of a file, and then setting `attrib +r` for Read-Only status. This works locally, but when the file is copied over to a specific network drive, the Read-Only attribute is removed. Similarly, the attribute cannot be set for a file already on the drive. Other drives are not affected in this way, and I can modify all files on the affected drive.

Is the issue permissions-related, despite my ability to modify files in all other ways?

Comment: Comparing the file system of your network drive and the ones where attrib works may help

Comment: One possible cause is that the file system on the network drive in question simply doesn't support the read-only attribute.  For example, it might be a Linux file server.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Should I still see the Read Only attribute in Properties for the files stored on this drive if it's a Linux file server?

Comment: You mean, on some files the flag is set?  I don't know, but it isn't impossible - for example, Samba might report that a file's read-only attribute is set based on the permissions on the file.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Sorry, I mean that when I view properties for a file on the affected network drive, I still see the Read Only attribute as a check box I can alter (though it never saves when I alter it). Would I see this if it were Linux?

Comment: Yes.  Windows doesn't know whether the server will actually respect flag changes or not, so it can't change the GUI accordingly.